# How to use multiple databases like multiple languages in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two database to support two languages for my application.

I want to change database when I change language from settings.

Is it possible?? How can i do this?

Comment: You could also make a different table called `translations` where you store all the names and stuff. For example if you have a table `products` with an  `productid` a table `product_translations` with a column `productid`, `languagekey` and the translation. (Just a way I did it in the past)

Comment: your mean is use one database???

Comment: Yes I used only one database, just 2 tables.

Comment: No. I don't want oane database. beacause my database is very complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using **Ridcully** solution, you will need to add only the database name part,
all you need to add is the class you extend.

this example from the library you mentioned:

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {


    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        // here comes the magic:
        String dbName = context.getString(R.string.db_name);
        super(context, dbName , null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

The other database class can be:

```
public class MyDatabase2 extends SQLiteAssetHelper {


    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        // here comes the magic:
        String dbName = context.getString(R.string.db_name_2);
        super(context, dbName , null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** to use SQLiteAssetHelper, u need to create the database yourself, and put in the assets/databases folder.

you can create sqlite database with this app [Sqlitebrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)

Answer (score 4):

It should be possible quite easily when you provide a string resource with the name of the database:

In `/res/values/strings.xml` put a line like this:

```
<string name="db_name">database</string>
```

In `/res/values-de/strings.xml` put that line:

```
<string name="db_name">database_de</string>
```

And in your DBHelper class use the database name of the strings file currently active according to language settings:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final static int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static DBHelper sInstance;

    /**
     * Provides access to DBHelper singleton.
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static DBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        // Use the application context, which will ensure that you
        // don't accidentally leak an Activity's context.
        // See this article for more information: http://bit.ly/6LRzfx
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new DBHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor should be private to prevent direct instantiation.
     * make call to static factory method "getInstance()" instead.
     */
    private DBHelper(Context context) {
        // here comes the magic:
        String dbName = context.getString(R.string.db_name);
        super(context, db_name, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
         // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I will try it. But I have a little problem. I use preloaded database with this link: [android sqlite asset helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: Why don't you ask @MBH, who's answer (which is a copy of mine) you accepted??